# A master RAML file with references to child RAMLs

Tags: rest, api, raml

I have 2 RAML files (the must be v0.8) completely describing 2 resources: animals.raml and plants.raml.

They both contain something like:

```
#%RAML 0.8
---
title: Animals API
baseUri: http://something/
documentation:
  - title: Overview
    content: The */animals* resource allows you to...
mediaType: application/json

protocols:
  - HTTPS

/animals:
  post:
    description: Create a new animal
    body:
      schema: !include ./schemas/animal.schema.json
    responses:
      202:
        description: In a few months, your new pet will be born.
```

Now I would like to have a master file, api.raml, that would give a generic overview about the animals and plants resources.
The API reader would navigate to the api.raml and from there he would be able to navigate again to the specific raml. Or it can be all inlined, on the same page.

I naively tried

```
#%RAML 0.8
---
title: Zoo & Botanical garden APIs
documentation:
  - title: Overview
    content: The *Zoo & Botanical garden APIs* contain resources that allow you to ...

resourceTypes: !include animals.raml
resourceTypes: !include plants.raml
```

Obviously very naive, failed with many complaints about the *title* elements and many other.

How should I approach creating the master api.raml which basically need to contain only a generic info and then include/link to the specific RAMLs?

Comment: I was just curious about RAML so I looked at this question. Given my *instant I'll google that for you knowledge*, this [seems to be the correct way](https://forum.raml.org/t/include-external-resources-raml-file-in-one-uber-file/212/2) to include external file references. It seems relevant that there can only be one top level root element. Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks for the link, @SixtoSaez, the uber RAML is exactly what I'm creating.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have "resourceTypes:" keyword twice, you either separate your resource types like this:

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Example API
version: v1
resourceTypes:
   - collection: !include resourceTypes/collection.raml
   - member: !include resourceTypes/member.raml
```

or you include everything in one file and do like this:

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Example API
version: v1
resourceTypes: !include resourceTypes.raml
```

Check [here for more info on how to use includes](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-08/raml-08.md#includes).